# A new session could not be created Original error:com.xxx.xxx/ view.activity.ActivityStart never started

Tags: java, android, appium

When I run the basic appium code app launched properly but  i got below Error.
Application is loaded properly but test is getting failed.

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: XXX.XXX.XXX.view.activity.ActivityStart never started.

 Current: com.XXX.XXXcom.pearsoned.auth.ui.AuthenticationActivity) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 32.99 seconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50'
System info: host: 'LKSRIWL-9Y3BF72', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:27)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:22)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:202)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:50)
    at com.pearson.eselenium.liverPool.testmob.WhatsApp.testapp(WhatsApp.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.XXX.XXX.liverPool.testmob.WhatsApp.quit(WhatsApp.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

This is my Apium code:

```
public class WhatsApp
{
 WebDriver dr;

 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 @Test
 public void testapp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
  File app = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\apks\\mediashare-debug.apk");

  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();

  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "motorola-nexus_6-ZX1G323XDM");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

  capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());


  dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
  dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


  // clicking
  Thread.sleep(10000);

 }

 @AfterMethod
 public void quit() {
  dr.quit();
 }
```

Appreciate help on this. 
Thank you!!

Comment: Instead of specifying apk path, Install app manually once and then try by mentioning app package and app activity?

Comment: Thanks Vinod this works for me .

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
```

These exception comes when appium not able establish any session between your device and itself.

It occurs because of following reason.

1. When you have not setting capabilities properly.(which includes appPackage, appPath, etc).
2. When device doesn't contains the application(.apk) which you mention in **appPackage**.
3. When you have mention wrong **appPath**.

In your case your appPath is wrong i.e **"\apks\mediashare-debug.apk"**

please mention write path or install application on your device.

Hope these help you.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says appium could not create a session with **the device**. Below are the compulsory capabilities you need to pass in order to create a session with the device and start execution.

```
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.flipkart.android");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", 
"com.flipkart.android.SplashActivity");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Ash");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("udid", "45s56f82r6");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("app","YourAppPath/Flipkart_com.flipkart.android.apk");
mobileCapabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true");
```

In case of iOS you don't need to pass appPackage and appActivity.